# Can I define an interface that allows me to call a custom method on specific strings?

Tags: typescript, extension-methods

I have a database that returns objects like this:

```
interface Bicycle {
  id: string;
  created_at: string;
}
```

I know that `created_at` holds a machine-friendly date that I will need to transform into a Date object for localization: `new Date(bike.created_at)`.

Instead of defining `created_at` as a vanilla string, I would like to define it as a type that extends string with a method I can call to convert it to a date: `bike.created_at.toDate()`.

This would give an easy, type-safe way to get Date objects from these strings that hold dates, as guaranteed by the database.

The implementation might look like this:

```
interface DateString extends string {
  toDate(): Date;
}

interface Bicycle {
  id: string;
  created_at: DateString;
}
```

However, this won't work unless I mutate the string prototype to "monkey-patch" my implementation of `toDate`. I understand that mutating the prototype is bad practice because it can cause unpredictable behavior. I also don't want to make `toDate` available on all the other strings in my app that aren't dates.

I could instead write a transformer that takes the object from the database and replaces the `created_at` string with a date. But that seems more fragile than my attempted example where `created_at` is a string marked as having a special date purpose.

Comment: How would replacing strings with dates be fragile? This approach seems *more* fragile and prone to bugs to me.

Comment: So, what is `Bicycle.created_at` now? Is it an exotic string-like object with the `toDate` method, or is it a simple string?

Comment: `created_at` is an ISO date string, such as "2017-05-29T23:18:13.263Z"

Answer (score 0):

If `toDate` only exists on `Bicycle.created_at`, you can define an intersection of `string` and a custom object with `toDate` method:

```
interface WithToDate {
    toDate(): Date
}

type CreatedAt = string & WithToDate

interface Bicycle {
  id: string;
  created_at: CreatedAt;
}
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/NDAyzm)*.

Note however that this is only the typings side of the things. If you want to actually use `.toDate` at runtime, it has to be actually implemented. And since it is likely to be implemented as a method on a `String.prototype`, all strings will have `.toDate` method.

Answer (score 0):

Another popular approach (instead of modifying the prototype or modifying the properties directly on a `string` value) is to use [Branded Types](https://dev.to/andersonjoseph/typescript-tip-safer-functions-with-branded-types-14o4) (see also: [Matt Pocock's Twitter Thread](https://twitter.com/mattpocockuk/status/1625173884885401600?s=20)). tl;dr, it allows you create functions that only accepts a subset of possible values at the type level without any effect on the runtime.

If you're worried about the use of `as`, it's valid to use `as` here since this just adds type information to a `string` type at development time but not anything at runtime.

One place in your codebase, or imported from a library, should be this code:

```
declare const brand: unique symbol;

type Brand<T, TBrand extends string> = T & {
  [brand]: TBrand;
};
```

Then you can create your own branded type:

```
type DateString = Brand<string, "DateString">;
```

(you can also make a branded type like below, but if you're using multiple branded types, you might prefer the generic)

```
declare const brand: unique symbol;

type DateString = string & {
 [brand]: "DateString";
};
```

Once you have a branded type, you can have a function that requires it at compile time (has no effect at runtime):

```
function toDate(dateString: DateString) {
  return new Date(dateString);
}
```

```
const d1 = toDate("foo"); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DateString'
const d2 = toDate("Tue, 15 Aug 2023 21:06:50 GMT"); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DateString'
const d3 = toDate("Tue, 15 Aug 2023 21:06:50 GMT" as DateString); // works
```

Your `Bicycle` interface can look like

```
interface Bicycle {
  id: string;
  created_at: DateString;
}
```

Let's say you have a database/api call that returns an array of Bicycles:

```
// A fake async function to mock a database/api call
async function getBicycles(): Promise<Bicycle[]> {
  return [
    {
      id: "foo",
      created_at: "Tue, 15 Aug 2023 21:06:50 GMT" as DateString, // Manual assignments require `as`, abstract to a function if you want
    },
    {
      id: "bar",
      created_at: "Wed, 16 Aug 2023 09:10:09 GMT" as DateString,
    },
  ];
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
const myBicycles = await getBicycles();

const createdAts = myBicycles.map(({created_at}) => toDate(created_at));

console.log(createdAts);

const foo = myBicycles.find(({id}) => id === "foo");
if (foo) {
  const favoriteDate = toDate(foo.created_at);
  console.log(`My favorite date is ${favoriteDate}`);
}
```

Overriding prototypes of built-in types brings in a lot of potential for being incompatible with future versions of JS, especially in library code. Whenever possible, a function that takes in a native type is safer, and branded types allow you to conditionally allow some inputs at the type level without affecting runtime.

[TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NdOAYw)